# unstack/pivot/melt, which one to use?

Tags: python, pandas, melt

`df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amanaroratc/hello-world/master/ask_pivot.csv')`

I have a dataframe of the format:
[image]

Every date has maximum of two unique Offer_Description.

I want to create new columns "Offer_1" and "Offer_2" and create single row for each date.

I am confused on using pivot_table or unstack or melt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by both columns, set to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['Product_ID','Date']).cumcount().add(1)
df = (df.set_index(['Product_ID','Date', g])['Offer_Description']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('Offer_')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
```

---

```
     Product_ID        Date  \
0       1067995  2021-12-16   
1       1067995  2021-12-17   
2       1067995  2021-12-19   
3       1067995  2021-12-20   
4       1067995  2021-12-22   
..          ...         ...   
345     4524075  2022-02-15   
346     4524075  2022-02-16   
347     4524075  2022-02-19   
348     4524075  2022-02-20   
349     4524075  2022-02-21   

                                               Offer_1  \
0      Additional 10% off on purchase worth Rs. 1000/-   
1      Additional 10% off on purchase worth Rs. 1000/-   
2      Additional 15% off on purchase worth Rs. 1500/-   
3      Additional 15% off on purchase worth Rs. 1500/-   
4         Additional 5% Off on purchase of 2+ products   
..                                                 ...   
345                           Buy 2 Get 10% Off on MRP   
346                           Buy 2 Get 10% Off on MRP   
347  Free Autographed Pouch By Janhvi Kapoor On Ord...   
348  Free Autographed Pouch By Janhvi Kapoor On Ord...   
349  Buy 2 Get 1 Free! *(Add 3 singles to the cart ...   

                                               Offer_2  
0      Additional 15% off on purchase worth Rs. 1500/-  
1      Additional 15% off on purchase worth Rs. 1500/-  
2                                                  NaN  
3                                                  NaN  
4                                                  NaN  
..                                                 ...  
345                                                NaN  
346                                                NaN  
347                                                NaN  
348                                                NaN  
349  Free Autographed Pouch By Janhvi Kapoor On Ord...  

[350 rows x 4 columns]
```